# Red Hat OpenShift: cannot build/deploy node app because "Output image could not be resolved"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, openshift

I have linked my GitHub repo to an OpenShift app, added the main property and start script to the package.json, but under Builds, it says "Status: Output image could not be resolved. Started: not started"

Comment: Can you include the actual logs from running ``oc logs build/thebuildname``, replacing ``thebuildname`` with the actual value? Better that can see the whole output for context.

Comment: When I try to download the oc command, I get "Active Subscription Required". I would prefer not to pay to download the command. https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/cli_reference/get_started_cli.html#cli-mac

Comment: Did you install OpenShift Origin, or OpenShift Container Platform? If using OpenShift Origin you should not be trying to access the images from Red Hat registry for OCP, use the Origin images from Docker Hub.

Comment: Unfortunate I thought Open Shift was one thing by itself. I did not install anything, but I have an application on an Open Shift dashboard, so I think I am using Red Hat OpenShift Container Platform

Comment: So you are using an OpenShift instance provided by your company? If you haven't installed anything, the only other option might be that you are using the hosted service called OpenShift Online.

Comment: Yup, I'm using OpenShift Online - so many open OpenShifts!

Comment: Hi, have you first tried to do something like oc create imagestream ?

Comment: No - that wasn't in the tutorial I was reading

Answer (score 6):

I was running into the exact same error message.  It turns out I had all my OpenShift resources in place except the *ImageStream* to store the build output images into.  Like @pixie recommended, try to run 
`oc create imagestream <imagestream name from build config>` and see if it helps with your build.